# Running background task while phone is locked iOS

Tags: ios, background

I currently set up a background task that keeps a timer running for 5 minutes. If my phone is unlocked it works fine, but once it's locked, the timer never triggers my selector. Is this intended behavior or did I do something wrong?

Comment: No, that is intended behaviour. You can't rely on background execution for long periods on iOS

Comment: Even if I set it up with [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ?

Comment: It may execute for a few minutes but there is a limit over the lifetime of your app, so you probably can't expect this to work more than once or twice per launch.

Comment: Where can I find the limit over the lifetime of my app?

Comment: You can examine the backgroundTimeRemaining property of UIApplication - https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/backgroundTimeRemaining - the limit can change, and indeed changed from about 10 minutes in iOS 6 to about 3 minutes in iOS 7

Comment: It doesn't seem to specify that the backgroundTimeRemaining is a pool of time over the lifetime of the app - it seems to imply that this is some amount of time given every time the app goes to the background.

Comment: True, perhaps that was confusing on my part - if you exceed this time then your app is killed and is no longer in the background.

Comment: Right, but I thought as long as we have an expiration callback that ends the task we should be okay (we terminate the task when it expires)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64663/discussion-between-paulw11-and-user3854397).